# No ground screw on Amana LE8317L2 Dryer

Tags: electrical, dryer

I am hooking up a 4 wire cord to a 3 wire dryer. I don’t see a green screw but there are two other green cords with a stripe on them that I can’t seem to turn.

Where should the green wire from my cord go?

Those are the only other screws in that terminal area.

[image]

Comment: A clearer photo with more context would be good. There may be something you're not showing us.

Comment: Looks like a punched hole below the terminal block the grounding screws are usually 10-32 self forming (not self tapping).

Comment: The hole which looks like it's behind the white wire (but in reality is probably further to the left) looks like it might be threaded for a ground screw.

Comment: Those are the only other screws in there. The original picture was too big to upload. It’s an old dryer so it may not have a ground screw, or so I’ve read. Neither are green as a normal ground screw would be.

Answer (score 3):

### I'd try the hole on the back, behind the white wire

I'd try threading a 10-32 grounding screw into the open hole on the back side of the wiring compartment and using that to land your ground.  If that hole's the wrong size, then I'd get a Garvin GSST and *carefully* drive it into the sheet metal enclosing the wiring comparment, then land the grounding lead from the cord on that.

Comment: There appear to be 2 grounding wires attached in the background. Would there be any reason to _not_ undo one of those screws then tighten it back down with a 2nd grounding lug under it? (Assuming, of course, that the currently unattached wire will reach.)

Comment: @FreeMan -- sharing grounding connections under a single screw generally isn't considered good practice (and probably wouldn't have passed UL muster in a factory design)

Comment: I was unaware of that. Thank you.